# Updating UINavigationBar Title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a split view controller and a navigationcontroller on the left side. As views are pushed onto the nav controller I'm attempting to change the Navigation Bar title. The problem seems to be that the text can only be updated in `viewWillAppear`. If I try to change the text after that initial load, it doesn't update. At first I thought I needed to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the NavigationItem, but it doesn't have a property. I don't understand because the same code works in `viewWillAppear` but not once the view is shown.

### I'm using:

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        self.title = @"blah";
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `self.navigationItem.title = @"Some Title";`

Comment: I've tried `self.navigationItem.title`, `self.navigation.navigationItem.title` and `self.title`, none of which update.

Comment: Well I would suggest you set the `titleView` to a label instead, and update that.

Comment: Bizarrely, this doesn't work. I'm adding a standard UILabel in the pushed ViewController's viewDidLoad, then doing `[((UILabel*)[pushedVc.navigationItem.titleView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) setText:@"Blah"];`, but the title view is still set to the text with which the label was initialized when I created it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: If you've set the `titleView` as a label, you shouldn't need to do all that subviews stuff. `[(UILabel *)self.navigationItem.titleView setText:@"My Title"]`

Comment: self.navigationItem.titleView = myNewLabel;

Answer (score 0):

I've set up a simple project where initial controller is embedded in navigation controller, and the second controller is pushed onto the navigation stack. Second controller has a button which calls this bit of code:

```
- (IBAction)changeTitle:(id)sender {

    static unsigned int i = 1;

    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of changes: %ud", i];

    i++;

}
```

It works as intended. Clearly it happens after all appear/layout events. So your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe `self` that you are referring to is a wrong controller.

Answer (score -3):

self.navigationBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TOP"];